# Calculation in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

There is a table

```
  Name    Sales1    Sales2

  A         10       20

  b         30      40
```

want a table

```
Sale    A     B

Sales1   33%   66%

Sales2   42%   57%
```

The calculation is like for Sales1 --> A it will be 10/(10+20)*100

Sales2--->b it will be 20/(10+20)*100

sames goes for sales2

How can it will be done?

Comment: What SQL have you actually tried?

Comment: select name,sum(sales1)/(select sum(sales1) from table_1) *100 from table_1 group by name

Comment: @SaNa3819 check my solution..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select a.name, cast(a.Sales1 as decimal(9,2))/cast(total as decimal(9,2))* 100 as  Percentage1, cast(a.Sales2 as decimal(9,2))/cast(total as decimal(9,2))* 100 as Percentage2
from 
(
    select *, (Sales1 + Sales2) as total
    from yourtable
) a
```

Edit: added extra casting for division :) working fiddle targeting sql server 2008: [Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d7f780/10)

Edit updated answer with basic `case` logic:

```
Select case when a.name = 'A' then 'Sales1' else 'Sales2' end as Sale, cast(a.Sales1 as decimal(9,2))/cast(total as decimal(9,2))* 100 as  Percentage1, cast(a.Sales2 as decimal(9,2))/cast(total as decimal(9,2))* 100 as Percentage2
from 
(
   select *, (Sales1 + Sales2) as total
   from yourtable
) a
```

Answer (score 0):

Though you should have tried but here you go..TESTED!

```
 select sale, (a/(a+b))*100, (b/(a+b))*100 from `table`
```

here is the schema I tested on

```
CREATE TABLE `table` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `sale` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `a` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',  
   `b` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Since the question is tagged `SLQ Server 2008` running this in sql fiddle for example will return zeroes :). It's fine for MySql but not for SQL Server 2008 unfortunately...

Comment: sql serve wont allow + operation like i mentioned?